# create dynamic controls with div in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create dynamic div with controls inside it. my code is below.

```
TextBox tb_name = new TextBox();
tb_name.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='form-group'><div class='clearfix' style='margin-top:15px;'></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-3'>"+tb_name +"</div></div></div>"));
```

But it is displaying like `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: `<input type='text' id='" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() +"' runat='server'/>` hence the complete code will be looks like the following:

```
  panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='form-group'><div class='clearfix' style='margin-top:15px;'></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-3'><input type='text' id='" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() +"' runat='server'/></div></div></div>"));
```

Comment: why not? use `runat='server'` to access it in code-behind

Comment: how to get the textbox value which is created in another button click